# Seat Management for Bus Reservation System

Tags: mysql, database-design

Am designing a database for bus reservation System and I cannot figure out how to Limit seats in some scenarios. 
Suppose I have Bus Stops A-B-C-D-E which forms a route from A to E through C and D. The bus is having 10 seats. Now if 10 seats are booked from A-B the and another 10 for D-E, system should allow booking for B-C, B-D and C-D.I can't figure out how to make a design that will cater for all scenarios to avoid booking the route that is already full.

I plan to use PHP for development with MySQL. Here is the relevant part of database design (database itself is too big and I tried to make a simple demo)

[image: Database]

Comment: it would be nice to say why down-vote. That would make question better as I believe its valid question (after extensive SO search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the scenario correctly I would do something like this:

```
ID|busStop|routeTime
1 | A | 01:00
```

in this table all your bookings go, so for each booking one row is made.
So now you can calculate how much bookings are made for each stop on each route and how many seats are left.

Does this answer your question?

EDIT: ofcourse you should add a column for the ID of the account that made the booking too.

EDIT2: Instead of using a busStop column you could use a busDrive (or something similar to that) column wich does not store the busstops A, B ... but stores the route A - B, B - C.

So let's say a customer books the ride A-B, The row gets added with a value A-B. We can calculate that route A-B has 9 seats left. So now if there are 10 records of A-B in the database for this bus ride, we know there are no seats left for the route A-B.

Ofcourse you can create a table next to it with the bus stops itself in it

Is this what you want?

EDIT3:

user table:

```
ID|username ...
```

busstop table:

```
ID|busstop|userID ...
```

busdrive table

```
ID|busdrive|userID ...
```

userID refers to the ID column in the user table.

EDIT 4: So now when someone books from A-D you make three records in busdrive with values A-B, B-C and C-D

Comment: The route is made of two Stops I need to cover scenarios as stated i the question.

Comment: Don't worry about other fields, they are there in production. I just stripped it to minima to make my point

Comment: The Problem comes when A-C is full, A-B and B-C are automatically full because that guy does occupy seat from A to C

Comment: So (edit4) With each route I need to insert whole set of mathematical combination, right i.e AC = AB, BC, AC and AD= AB, BC, BD, AD?

Comment: can you edit and expand edit 4, its the answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

I think you going to have to start out with a Table that contains each endpoint with it's associated parent.

So table 1 has each route point defined

```
RouteId : "A"
RouteName "My A Route"

RouteId : "B"
RouteName "My B Route"
```

Table 2 (Paths) would define how routes connect :

```
PathId :"P1"
RouteId : "B"
ParentRouteId : "A"
```

Now you can use a third table to keep track on who's riding what route and what it's parent is thus accumulating the total number of passengers.

I know this is somewhat vague, but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: can you explain of the third table. Its in the right track

Answer (score 0):

To store the seat tracking information. you can come up with table(Seat Mapping).
Let's say the origin and destination of the bus is A->E.
So we have following valid paths to book the ticket for:
A->B, B->C, C->D, D-E.

Say, U1 wants to book a seat say 32A for A-E.
Seat Mapping table will look like this:

```
SeatId  ---- Source ----- Destination
 32A          A            B
 32A          B            C
 32A          C            D
 32A          D            E
```

So if any user wants to book ticket for a route say C - E
you can simply query the table for the seat availability as below.

select seatId where source != 'C' and destination != 'E';

Also, lets say another user U2, wants to book seat 32B between A and C
now the entry will look like

```
 SeatId  ---- Source ----- Destination
 32A          A            B
 32A          B            C
 32A          C            D
 32A          D            E
 32B          A            B
 32B          B            C
```

and if another user say U3, wants to book a seat between A to D
from the above query this will not return any seat.
select seatId where source != 'A' and destination != 'D';

Hope this answer your question.